# Is it possible to calculate expected amountIn or amountOut for a Uniswap V3 swap in Solidity without executing the swap?

Tags: solidity, uniswapv3

I am currently attempting to plan a trade on-chain in Uniswap V3 and I need to determine the exact amount of tokens that will be involved in the swap. To achieve this, I have researched [Uniswap V3 documentation](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/periphery/lens/QuoterV2) and discovered the `Quoter` contract. However, according to the documentation, Quoter is not gas efficient and its functions are not intended to be used as part of an on-chain execution. Additionally, they appear to [revert as part of their normal behavior](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/8943ee4047ea7892685802e4baf5f913993844fa/contracts/interfaces/IQuoter.sol#L7-L8) in order to calculate the result, which makes them unsuitable for on-chain execution.

As such, I am wondering if it is possible to pre-calculate amountIn in a manner suitable for on-chain execution without executing the swap. I am uncertain if this is achievable, so any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Uniswap V3, there is currently no gas-efficient way to calculate the exact amount of tokens that would go into or out of a swap on-chain without executing the swap.

However, it is possible to optimistically execute the swap and check the amounts in the callback. This means that a user can flash borrow an amount tokens from the Uniswap V3 pool, and expect the flash borrow to be repaid in the other token in the pool. The following code initiates the optimistic swap:

```
/// @notice Flash borrows underlying from Uniswap V3, liquidates the underwater account, and repays the flash loan.
function flashLiquidate(FlashLiquidateParams memory params) external override {
        ...
        // Compute the flash pool key and address.
        vars.poolKey = PoolAddress.getPoolKey({
            tokenA: address(params.collateral),
            tokenB: address(vars.underlying),
            fee: params.poolFee
        });

        vars.zeroForOne = address(vars.underlying) == vars.poolKey.token1;

        IUniswapV3Pool(poolFor(vars.poolKey)).swap({
            // The recipient of the flash borrowed underlying tokens.
            recipient: address(this),
            // The direction of the swap, true for token0 to token1, false for token1 to token0.
            zeroForOne: vars.zeroForOne,
            // the amount of underlying tokens to flash borrow from the Uniswap V3 pool
            amountSpecified: int256(params.underlyingAmount) * -1,
            // The limit for the price the swap will push the pool to.
            // Here it is set to global maximum or minimum possible price depending on swap direction.
            sqrtPriceLimitX96: vars.zeroForOne ? MIN_SQRT_RATIO + 1 : MAX_SQRT_RATIO - 1,
            // Data to be passed to swap callback.
            data: abi.encode(
                UniswapV3SwapCallbackParams({
                    bond: params.bond,
                    borrower: params.borrower,
                    collateral: params.collateral,
                    poolKey: vars.poolKey,
                    sender: msg.sender,
                    turnout: params.turnout,
                    underlyingAmount: params.underlyingAmount
                })
            )
        });
}
```

The code above flash borrows `underlyingAmount` from the provided Uniswap V3 pool and expects the flash borrow to be repaid in the other token in the pool, which is the liquidated collateral `repayAmount`.

Once the optimistic swap is initiated, the `uniswapV3SwapCallback` function is called. Here, the exact amount of tokens required to execute the swap is calculated, which is `repayAmount` in the code example provided. This enables the user to get the output amount of tokens first optimistically and then repay the flash borrowed amount in the other pool token in the callback.

```
 /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3SwapCallback
    function uniswapV3SwapCallback(
        int256 amount0Delta,
        int256 amount1Delta,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external override {
        UniswapV3SwapCallbackLocalVars memory vars;

        // Unpack the ABI encoded data passed by the UniswapV3Pool contract.
        UniswapV3SwapCallbackParams memory params = abi.decode(data, (UniswapV3SwapCallbackParams));

        // Check that the caller is the Uniswap V3 flash pool contract.
        if (msg.sender != poolFor(params.poolKey)) {
            revert FlashUniswapV3__CallNotAuthorized(msg.sender);
        }

        // Mint hTokens and liquidate the borrower.
        vars.mintedHTokenAmount = mintHTokens(...);

        // Calculate the exact amount of collateral required to repay.
        vars.repayAmount = uint256(amount0Delta > 0 ? amount0Delta : amount1Delta);

        // Note that "turnout" is a signed int. When it is negative, it acts as a maximum subsidy amount.
        // When its value is positive, it acts as a minimum profit.
        if (int256(vars.seizeAmount) < int256(vars.repayAmount) + params.turnout) {
            revert FlashUniswapV3__TurnoutNotSatisfied({
                seizeAmount: vars.seizeAmount,
                repayAmount: vars.repayAmount,
                turnout: params.turnout
            });
        }

        // Reap the profit.
        if (vars.seizeAmount > vars.repayAmount) {
            unchecked {
                vars.profitAmount = vars.seizeAmount - vars.repayAmount;
            }
            params.collateral.safeTransfer(params.sender, vars.profitAmount);
        }

        // Pay back the Uniswap V3 flash borrow.
        params.collateral.safeTransfer(msg.sender, vars.repayAmount);
}
```

See how we are calculating `repayAmount` in the callback, which is the exact amount of tokens that would need to go into the swap to get the desired output amount.

** Example above is a simplified version of FlashUniswapV3.sol from [hifi-finance/hifi](https://github.com/hifi-finance/hifi).

** Disclaimer: I work at Hifi Finance as a full-time blockchain engineer.

Comment: If you work for hifi-finance you should add a disclaimer otherwise the answer will be considered spam.

Comment: @Ismael Ok, thanks for this. I usually share code from my own personal research that's not relevant to my employment, but I'll make sure to make it a practice to add a disclaimer whenever I find myself in a similar situation in the future.

Comment: Just curious, the user is not actually swapping tokens during this process right?

Comment: @Wuzhong-ChainstackDevEx Well, not in the conventional sense. The code above basically borrows an amount of the underlying token from the given Uniswap V3 pool, liquidates a given underwater position on the lending protocol, takes just enough of the liquidated collateral token to repay the Uniswap V3 borrow, and pockets the any leftover collateral as profit. Note that the pool is made up of the underlying token and the collateral token.

Comment: Another way to look at it would be as swapping the liquidated collateral (in) for the borrowed underlying (out), which might sound confusing. But that's basically how both Uniswap V2 and Uniswap V3 handle swaps: you first receive the amount of output tokens, then you are expected to send the necessary amount input tokens in order to have the swap transaction execute successfully. This is how it's possible for the code above to execute a swap without requiring the calling EOA to hold any token amount(s).

Answer (score 1):

developer advocate from Chainstack here.

You can try Ethereum's [trace_call](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/ethereum/trace_call) method in this case.

A trace_call is similar to eth_call, which doesn't really send a transaction but rather "simulates" the transaction's execution locally.

`eth_call` only returns the execution result so it may not fit into your case. `trace_call` provides additional execution information, for example, log and state changes, which may come in handy.

However, not many providers give access to this API because it is very computationally intensive. It is available on [Chainstack](https://docs.chainstack.com/operations/ethereum/debug-and-trace-apis) with a cost.

Comment: Sorry, that does not answer how to do it on-chain. I've posted the answer above.

Comment: I guess we have different understandings of "on-chain".

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. How would you recommend I phrase a similar situation next time to avoid any misunderstanding?

Comment: Or perhaps help me edit how the question is currently phrased.

Comment: I think the problem is that you did not specify that you had to use an on-chain method. You just said that you would need data `suitable for on-chain execution`

Comment: My understanding of "on-chain" is the opposite of "off-chain";  which usually refers to any data/service unrelated to the blockchain.   

Your question is OK. I just didn't realize you were asking for methods that can be used "during execution".  Yeah, thanks to Markus for pointing this out. If you want to rephrase it, how about explicitly stating that you are talking about a methodology that can be used during "contract execution"? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static call to simulate a transaction. With ethers you can get the `amountIn` like this

```js
const amountOut = await quoter.callStatic.quoteExactInput(..);
```

see more info in the [docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/contract/contract/-%23-contract-callStatic).

In case you have to handle a reverting transaction on-chain you could use [`try/catch`](https://solidity-by-example.org/try-catch/) or parse the low level call ([see this example by Uniswap](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/5bcdd9f67f9394f3159dad80d0dd01d37ca08c66/contracts/lens/Quoter.sol#L60-L64)).

Comment: Sorry, the provided on-chain method is not gas efficient at all. I've posted the answer to this question.